# Incorrect syntax - T-Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

The idea is to have a generic stored procedure to get data from all tables. This query gives an error

> Incorrect Syntax new @OrderByClause.

Where am I going wrong?

```
declare @TableName nvarchar(50), @ColName nvarchar(50), 
        @OrderByClause nvarchar(50), @Code nvarchar(max), 
        @StartIndex nvarchar(50), @EndIndex nvarchar(50)

set @TableName = 'tblCountry'
set @ColName = 'countryname'
set @OrderByClause = 'desc'
set @StartIndex = '2'
set @EndIndex = '10'

select @Code = 'With temp as (select row_number() 
               over (order by @ColName @OrderByClause) as row, * from @TableName)
               select * from temp where row between @StartIndex and @EndIndex'

set @param = '@TableName nvarchar(50), @ColName nvarchar(50), 
              @OrderByClause nvarchar(50), @StartIndex nvarchar(50), 
              @EndIndex nvarchar(50)'

execute sp_executesql @Code, @param @colname, @OrderByClause, @TableName, 
                      @StartIndex, @EndIndex
```

**EDIT**:

This is working though....

```
select @code = 'with temp as (select row_number() over (order by '+
                @colname+' '+@OrderByClause+') as row, * from '+@tablename+')
select * from temp where row between '+@startIndex+' and '+@EndIndex

execute sp_executesql @code
```

Comment: You can't parameterise arbitrary parts of the SQL as you are trying. The point of using dynamic SQL here is to create the desired string through concatenation first for the parts that can't be parameterised. Read up on SQL injection and the `QUOTENAME` function [here](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)

Answer (score 2):

You missed a comma on the last statement:

```
execute sp_executesql @Code, @param @colname, @OrderByClause, @TableName,
```

should be

```
execute sp_executesql @Code, @param, @colname, @OrderByClause, @TableName,
```

---

The second thing is that @RahulTripathi was correct (but for a different reason), this is invalid:

```
select @Code = 'With temp as (select row_number() 
           over (order by @ColName @OrderByClause) as row, * from @TableName)
           select * from temp where row between @StartIndex and @EndIndex'
```

The `@OrderByClause` cannot be there because `ASC` and `DESC` are *syntactical* elements of the `ORDER BY` clause and cannot be variables.

Next, you have not defined @TableName correctly in the dynamic SQL.  You are using it as a Table variable in the commands above, *but* you are passing (and defining) it as an `NVarchar(50)`.

Comment: That SQL string shown in the question ain't gonna work as desired either!

Comment: oops my mistake, the comma is present in the query

Comment: @MartinSmith Oops. Yes, unlike T-SQL, I *do* short-circuit.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think your variables are not defined neither interpreted (in the case of desc) in the sp_executesql scope.
Try to "expand" before calling sp_executesql with + and quotes when you assign @code:

```
select @Code = 'With temp as (select row_number() 
               over (order by '+ @ColName +' '+ @OrderByClause +' ) as row, * from '+ @TableName +')
               select * from temp where row between '+ @StartIndex + ' and '+@EndIndex
```

(did only one row)

or you could pass parameters to sp_executesql but you will have to choose different names 
and not for @ColName, @tableName and @OrderByClause I guess (you can't put variables instead of sql text anywhere in a query)

```
select @Code = 'With temp as (select row_number() 
               over (order by '+@ColName+' '+@OrderByClause+') as row, * from '+@TableName+')
               select * from temp where row between @pStartIndex and @pEndIndex'
execute sp_executesql @code, @pStartIndex=@StartIndex, @pEndIndex=@EndIndex
```